# How does Java session work when I change the object

Tags: java, list, session, arraylist, shopping-cart

Recently, I am trying to write shopping cart with Java session.  I use List object to store products and then store in the session. When the user change the amount of the product is changed, I use the code below try to update the session. And it does work, cause when I refresh my page the number showing next to the cart icon is changed, but I really don't know how it works. Can anyone help me please ;/ ?
Here's the code when the user cancel a sprcific product, and I just remove from the list:

```
List<OrderProduct> orderProductList = (ArrayList<OrderProduct>)session.getAttribute("orderProductList");
for (int i = 0; i < orderProductList.size(); i ++) {
        if (orderProductList.get(i).getProduct().getId() == productID) {
            orderProductList.remove(i); 
        }
    }
```

My problem is I did not do this

```
    session.setAttribute(...)
```

but when I retrieve session in the jsp, the object stored in the session is changed, how does it works?

Comment: What session?  This is clearly not just a Java question.  Please specify what software stack you are using?

Comment: You're modifying a `List` (`orderProductList.remove(i);`) while you're iterating it. You should use an `Iterator` for that.

Comment: @Titus Why should I use Iterator? I just use for-loop instead.  And I do  `orderProductList.remove(i);` is because I want to delete it from the list

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing

Comment: @Titus it actually can't fail in the way that question describes - there is no iterator to get out of sync with the collection. It's still wrong since it ends up skipping list items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of an `HttpSession` as a kind of per-user `Map` that the servlet container maintains for you across requests. Once you initiate a session, the container generates a unique sessionid cookie and sets it in the response and gives you an instance with which you can associate your session data. For subsequent requests, the container takes care of identifying the sessionid cookie and giving you an instance of `HttpSession` with the data specific to that session. You don't need to call setAttribute just like if you had

```
SomeObj obj = new SomeObj();
Map<String, SomeObj> map = HashMap();
map.put("key", obj);
SomeObj o2 = map.get("key");
o2.setProperty("foo");
```

Now you've changed the state of obj while it is still in your map. You do not need to call map.put again.

Comment: Is this because when I set session attribute `session.setAttribute('orderProductList', list)` I named the session "orderProductList" and when I retrieve the session I use a List named "orderProductList" that makes the connection?

Comment: @hayley No, it created an attribute on the session called 'orderedProductList', mapped to your list. When you ask for the attribute again, you get the same list. Changing the list does not change the mapping, the session is still holding on to 'orderProductList' -> yourlistInstance. It doesn't matter what modifications you make to the list, the mapping is maintained.